# Simplifying $-\tan^2(x) -\sec(x)+\sec^2(x)$ into $1-\sec(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

It's in the title. I'm not sure how this is simplified, like I can't wrap my mind on the first step of simplifying this:
$$-\tan^2(x) -\sec(x)+\sec^2(x) = 1-\sec(x)$$
I'm not even sure on how the 1 has gotten there but I would assume that -$$\sec(x)+\sec^2(x) = \sec(x)$$ since $\sec^2(x)$ is basically just $2\sec(x)$, right?
Hopefully, the equation makes sense since it was a chunk that I took out of the whole question.

Comment: $\sec^2 x - \tan^2 x = 1$

Comment: $\sec^2(x)=(\sec(x))^2\ne 2\sec(x)$ unless $\sec(x)=2$.

Comment: As per the hint, if everything is single angle (IE all of (x) and not (2x)/etc.), you can usually reduce everything to $\sin$ and $\cos$ and use algebra and the one identity $\sin ^2(x)+\cos ^2 (x)=1$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$\sec^2(x)-\tan^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\ldots$$